# How to create alias with a caret^ command?

Tags: bash, alias, history-expansion

I have a workflow that first check `git diff` for specific file and then add it to stage.

```
git diff ..
```

```
^diff^add
```

I want to give these command a alias but this one doesn't work

```
alias da="^diff^add"
```

```
command not found: ^diff^add
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it that way. History substitution (i.e. the handling the `^` and `!`) is done before alias expansion.

Use `fc -s` instead:

```
$ alias da='fc -s diff=add'
$ echo git diff
git diff
$ da
echo git add
git add
```